# Change selected automatic numbered list to plain text in word

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I need to create a macro that will convert some automatically numbered lists to plain text. I found this macro below which will do the whole document perfectly, however I wish to keep the document titles etc still numbered automatically and just change the numbered list of requirements in the document to plain text.

```
Sub Auto_Format_convert_list_numbers()
'
' convert_list_numbers Macro
' Macro created 10/8/08 by WJ Shack
'
ActiveDocument.ConvertNumbersToText

End Sub
```

My thoughts on the subject were perhaps I could have it only do this to a list i have selected. (When i click on one of the numbered items it kind of highlights the others in the list) I tried the following but it gets an error

```
Sub Auto_Format_convert_list_numbers()
'
' convert_list_numbers Macro
' Macro created 10/8/08 by WJ Shack
'
Selection.ConvertNumbersToText

End Sub
```

Any suggestions? (I will keep pondering it myself but i'm sure as the whole document option is so simple there must be an easy way to do this!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ConvertNumbersToText` method isn't valid for `Selection`, but does work for the `List` class, so this sub will convert each List in the `ActiveDocument`:

```
Sub Auto_Format_convert_list_numbers()

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

'Change your pattern here
RE.Pattern = "[A-Z][A-z][0-9][0-9][-][0-9]"

For Each Lst In ActiveDocument.Lists
Set Match = RE.Execute(Lst.Range.Text)
If Match.Count Then
  Lst.ConvertNumbersToText
End If
Next    

End Sub
```

Comment: running this it still changes my heading numbers to plain text and therefore when i add a new heading in it starts at 1. I see that you use a for loop to go through each list therefore does each list have a unique indentifier? so I could choose to ignore the one for my headings? hah if this doesn't work i've got 300+ to go through and manually renumber :(

Comment: If you add `MsgBox Lst.Range.Text` you can see what each `List` contains, and you might be able to use `If` logic to filter those you don't want to convert. That looks like the only option as far as I can tell. N.B. Use `F8` to step through the code so you don't have to dismiss 300+ dialog boxes!

Comment: This ^ could work but I would implement it the opposite way round as each of the numbered requirements (the bits I want to change to plain text) follow the exact same format, therefore I could have it only change it to plain text if it followed the following format `[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][-][0-9]` ... I will try this later

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert just your Headings to text, this will do it for the entire document:

```
Sub ConvertHeadingNumbersToText()
    Dim paraCount As Integer
    paraCount = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
    Dim text As String
    Dim para As Paragraph
    ' process the headings bottoms up to preserve their original numbers
    For i = paraCount To 1 Step -1
        Set para = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i)
        If InStr(1, para.Style, "Heading") Then
            para.Range.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText
            text = para.Range.text   '  add a Watch for text so you can see progress in the Watches window
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Today I had exactly the same problem as OP, and come up with a simple solution:

```
Sub Selection_Convert_List_Numbers()
    Selection.Range.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText
End Sub
```