# Convert automatic numbering and bullets to plain text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document with automatic numbering and bulleting.

I have selected the text where I need to convert automating numbering and/or bulleting to normal text.

In addition I need to keep both the **formatting** and **numbers/bullets** of the selected text.

**What I have already tried**:

- cut the paragraphs and special pasted them (but it breaks formatting);
- unpressed the "numbering"/"bulleting" button (but it erases all numbers and bullets);
- used VBA-macro (but it returns an error):

Code (*error, method or data member not found*):

```
Sub convertNumbersAndBulletsToText()
   Selection.ConvertNumbersToText
End Sub
```

What would you recommend me to do in order to keep both formatting and numbers/bullets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have practically done everything yourself!

This code will work:

```
Sub convertNumbersAndBulletsToText()
   Selection.Range.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText
End Sub
```

Your example returns error because `ConvertNumbersToText` method doesn't work with `Selection`. It works with `Range`!

(look here: [Change selected automatic numbered list to plain text in word](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23339120/5410914))

---

**Beware**!

If you want to carry out many changes, you may find it easier to make them with `ActiveDocument` (look below).

But if want to do it manually (or through a loop),
then you'd better loop from the **last element** you want to convert **till the first** one
(not vice versa, because auto-numbers would then increment by one all the time)!

---

> **Small Tips**

Personally I would recommend you to use this code instead:

```
Sub convertNumbersAndBulletsToText()
   Dim myRange As Range
   Set myRange = Selection.Range
   myRange.ListFormat.ConvertNumbersToText
End Sub
```

- Why this one? It is a little bit more flexible! Instead of `Selection.Range` you could use any other type of `Range` (`ActiveDocument`, `ActiveDocument.Paragraphs`, `myRange.SetRange` etc)

  - Here are some links from msdn to give you basic examples of Ranges: 1) [Range Object (Word) (msdn)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/range-object-word), 2)
    [Range.SetRange Method (Word) (msdn)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/range-setrange-method-word).
- Just for your information, you don't need to save VBA if you don't want to. You can use Immediate Window to launch VBA.

  - Press `alt+f11` (VBA-editor), then `ctrl+g` (Immediate Window).
  - Paste the **code bellow**, press enter.
  - Voilà!

**Code** (for Immediate Window):

```
ActiveDocument.ConvertNumbersToText
```

(It converts auto-numbers and auto-bullets to normal numbers and bullets everywhere in `ActiveDocument`).

- The result of any VBA here would be `number+tab+text`. If you want to have `number+space+text` you can:

  - either at the very end replace (press `ctrl+h`) this one `.^t` (dot and tab) for `.` (dot and whitespace),
  - or at the very beginning 1) select the list, 2) right click on it, 3) click "Adjuct list idents", 4) click "Follow number with: Space". (Look here: [Adjust the spacing for a single list item (support.office)](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Change-the-indent-between-a-list-bullet-or-number-and-text-a2b7b2e4-9c74-4ca7-8fc4-52908f8efb22#bm2))
- You may need to have a leading zero in (auto-)numbering, then you can press `ctrl+f9`, write `SEQ MyList \# "000"` inside curly brackets, press `alt+f9` to finish (look here: [Insert fields in Word (support.office)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-fields-in-Word-c429bbb0-8669-48a7-bd24-bab6ba6b06bb)). But this goes beyond the question, though you may find word `fields` really useful in some cases.

---

> To sum up:

You can replace both bullets and numbers for plain text in Word:

- for Selection (look above);
- for ActiveDocument (look above);
- with a Range (examples in msdn);
- with a loop (examples are welcomed). But bear in mind that you are to loop from the end of the document to the beginning.

Comment: Is this supposed to work in Word 2016 too? It does not for me, just nothing happens.

Comment: @jumpjack, 1. All the three snippets are supposed to work! `Immediate Window` works for the whole document. The two other macros requires you to manually Select the word-fragment with auto-bulleted or auto-numbered text first (to convert needed text only)! To make sure the code works, write several auto-bulleted lines, then execute any of the two macros above (`Alt+F11`, `F5`, give macro name, create, paste the code). 3. If you wish to execute the code not for the selected selection, but for the whole document, you can replace the corresponding line with `Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range`